# What is the space complexity of declaring dict, and array in these following code?

Tags: python, algorithm

What is the space complexity of the following code since i declare the dict, and array?

--> to my assumption, I would say 0(n + m) since dict take o(n) space, and stack also take o(m) space. Am I correct?

```
hash_brackets = {
    "(":")",
    "{":"}",
    "[":"]"
}
        
stack = []
for bracket in s:
            
    if bracket in hash_brackets:
        stack.append(hash_brackets[bracket])
            
    elif len(stack) > 0 and bracket == stack[-1]:
        stack.pop()
    else:
        return False
        
return len(stack) == 0
```

Comment: The indenting of the code is wrong. Please [edit] to fix it. **Edit**: Also, you have two `return`s outside a function, and `s` is not defined.

Comment: Did you mean to mix big-O and little-o nottations? **Edit**: oh, actually, that's a zero, not a big-O. What does that mean?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Preface

The code as posted is invalid and incomplete, but it looks like the body of a function that checks if brackets are balanced. Filling in the gaps, I get this:

```
def balanced_brackets(s: str) -> bool:
    hash_brackets = {
        "(": ")",
        "{": "}",
        "[": "]"
    }

    stack = []
    for bracket in s:
        if bracket in hash_brackets:
            stack.append(hash_brackets[bracket])
        elif len(stack) > 0 and bracket == stack[-1]:
            stack.pop()
        else:
            return False
    return len(stack) == 0
```

Secondly, I assume you're asking about big-O complexity, not little-o.

---

The dict is O(1) because you don't add to it.

The list is O(n) because you add to it. Keep in mind big-O is an upper bound, and in this case, that would mean that every character in `s` is an open-bracket.